# How can I define each case of the choice list in a uitable (GUI) and put IF function for each one?

Tags: list, matlab, uitableview

I made a matlab gui that have two uitables, one of them have choice list format on its cells but I dont know how define each case of choice list and put IF function for each one. In other words I want apply numbers to second uitable from another gui with dependency on cases in the choice list of first uitable.

Comment: Hello and welcome at Stack Overflow :) Are your uitables in the same GUI or in different GUIs? Are you already familiar with callback functions, and what have you tried so far to solve your problem?

Comment: Actually, it is best practice to provide a [minimal complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) when you ask questions like this.

Comment: Hello and thank for your comment. When we make a uitable in MATLAB GUI, there is not general callback (such as push button) for uitable and we have only "cell edit callback" and "cell selection callback" that is inserted manually.First I would like to know How can I define each case of the choice list in a uitable with "cell edit callback" and "cell selection callback" and then  put IF function for each one?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you use `guide` to manage your GUI, and that you already have created a `uitable` with a column in the format of a choice list, and that you have set the `ColumnEditable` property to true. Is that the case?

Then, create a `CellEditCallback` function by right clicking on the `uitable` in the guide window and select "View Callbacks" -> "CellEditCallback". This will create the callback function if it doesn't exist so far.

The automatically created callback function could look like this:

```
% --- Executes when entered data in editable cell(s) in uitable1.
function uitable1_CellEditCallback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to uitable1 (see GCBO)
% eventdata  structure with the following fields (see MATLAB.UI.CONTROL.TABLE)
%   Indices: row and column indices of the cell(s) edited
%   PreviousData: previous data for the cell(s) edited
%   EditData: string(s) entered by the user
%   NewData: EditData or its converted form set on the Data property. Empty if Data was not changed
%   Error: error string when failed to convert EditData to appropriate value for Data
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
```

In this case, the tag of the `uitable` is `uitable1`. If your `uitable` has a different tag, the function name will be according to that tag.

Now, write your `if` block into this callback function. For example, if the choice list that you want to query is in the first row and first column of your `uitable`, and you want to check if the selected text of the decision box is "blabla", then your code would look like this:

```
if strcmp(handles.uitable1.Data{1,1}, 'blabla')
    % put here the code that you want to execute if the user selects 'blabla'
end
```

Hope it helps ...

Comment: Hello Amos and thank for your help. I used the code that you suggested but there was an error on command window : "Attempt to reference field of non-structure array."  and also :  Error in Sample>uitable1_CellEditCallback (line 86)
if strcmp(handles.uitable1.Data{1,1}, 'Lozenging').

Comment: What happens if you add the following code into a line before the `if` statement: `handles.uitable1` - does it give any output for the `uitable1` object?

Comment: The background of the question is, it seems that either `handles` is not a struct in your case, or `handles.uitable1` is not a struct.

Comment: @O.Rezapour If you like, you could paste the complete callback code into your question using the edit function. This way we can check your issue faster.